# Eclipse does not start on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, java, eclipse, jdk

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 and have been trying to install and use Eclipse ever since. I tried using both open JDK as well as Oracle JDK installations(both Java 7 and Java8) and both Eclipse Juno as well Eclipse Luna.

I even tried installing Eclipse from aptitude installer. All of them stop on the flash screen that Eclipse loads and start and hangs there. If any of you have faced similar problems and were able to get around this, please let me know.

I tried running the eclipse -debug option to see if there are any errors on the console but nothing showed up.

Thanks & Regards,
Nachiketh

Answer (score 2):

I add the follow line at the end of `eclipse.ini` file:

`-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla`

It worked for me, I hope you too.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem, and found a solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726191/eclipse-doesnt-start-in-ubuntu-14-04).

I just removed the old ~/workspace folder and, after starting 2 times (in the first time, Eclipse make a new ~/workspace folder and then close himself), the Eclipse works fine.